# How to configure SAML app in Google for AWS Client VPN and self service portal

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, vpn, google-workspace

I want to set up AWS Client VPN with SAML authentication through Google.

I got the actual VPN connection to work by following among others this: [AWS VPN using federated login with Google IdP - app_not_configured_for_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151685/aws-vpn-using-federated-login-with-google-idp-app-not-configured-for-user)

I'd like to also enable the self service portal with SAML authentication as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-authentication.html#federated-authentication Google only supports one ACS URL, so I am supposed to create a second app. While the above link is not super specific about it, I assume `urn:amazon:webservices:clientvpn` should be used for that as well. But when I try to create a second app I get an error saying the Entity ID should be unique and can't proceed because it's already used by the first app.

So the question is: how to I configure Google so I can use the Client VPN *and* the self service portal with SAML?

Comment: did you ever have any luck with this? Thanks...

Comment: @ambe5960 Nah, gave up on it. We have internal documentation anyway so I added the config file and other links there.

Comment: Thanks. Don't think it's possible. Check out perimeter81 for anyone struggling with this. Cheaper and more admin/user friendly.