# AWS client VPN not connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, aws-vpn

I created an AWS client VPN endpoint with a VPC using google federated authentication and server certificate generated using open easy-rsa. I tried to connect the VPN, but I keep getting Error: app_not_configured_for_user on the browser. I have searched online but I haven't found a possible solution. Does anyhow know how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is similar to the issue I was facing. Fjleon from reddit shared this link with me. Answer to my question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151685/aws-vpn-using-federated-login-with-google-idp-app-not-configured-for-user