# AWS VPN using Google IdP saml app - multiple CVPN endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpn

How do I use Google IdP for multiple AWS VPN endpoints?

I am able to set up Google as the IdP to use with AWS VPN using the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151685/aws-vpn-using-federated-login-with-google-idp-app-not-configured-for-user). I would like to use Google as the IdP for other AWS VPN endpoints (one for Dev and one for Prod). I am getting the error "Enter a unique entity ID, the one you entered is being used by another app." because the Entity ID is the same ("urn:amazon:webservices:clientvpn"). Does anyone know of a workaround for this?